# How can I apply curve filter to a video in Android

Tags: android, opencv, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

In Android how can I apply curve to a video using FFMPEG. 
Same like applying filters for a image.
Available curves in FFmpeg
none’
‘color_negative’
‘cross_process’
‘darker’
‘increase_contrast’
‘lighter’
‘linear_contrast’
‘medium_contrast’
‘negative’
‘strong_contrast’
‘vintage’

OpenCv has ffmpeg java implementation. But I can't able to figure out how to do it.
And how can I add custom effects.
Both NDK and OpenCv implementation is ok for me.